# Android: Location updates stop after some time (20-30 mins) in background

Tags: java, android, background, location, geo

I am building a web app to get the location updates. I know in the latest Android OS (oreo) the service needs to be foreground to get the location updates. But the current question is regarding previous versions of OS (< 6.0).
I am getting the location updates every second for 20-30 mins even when the app is running in the background. But these updates stop streaming all of a sudden.

I also tried the app as a background service to collect the updates but failed to get the consent of the user for the background service.

I would like to ask is there a way I can get the location updates in the idle mode or when the app is in the background (android OS <6.0).

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
DatabaseReference databaseValues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    databaseValues = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("values");
    WebView webb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web01);
    webb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webb.setClickable(true);
    webb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webb.loadUrl("https://www.foo.com/");

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
    else {
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    }
    startActivity(intent);

    String locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (locationProviders == null || locationProviders.equals("")) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            String GPSLocation = location.toString();

            String Lat = GPSLocation.substring(13,21).replace(',','.');
            String Lon = GPSLocation.substring(23,31).replace(',','.');

            addData(Lat,Lon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    }else {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        }else{
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code does work very well only for first 30-40 mins even in the background/idle state. Is it possible to keep getting the geo locations?

Answer (score 0):

As location Listeners are on main thread the activity might get Destroyed due to many reasons . I prefer to have location listeners in the sticky service and when ever i get a update will pass it to the Ui . You can use listeners to accomplish but i prefer to use live data to communicate from service to Ui to update the latest location and change ui accordingly

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service
{
private static final String TAG = "LocationService";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 10000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 50f;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
{
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tried making it as a service and receiving in the main activity as through broadcast receiver. But running as a service somehow is not activating my GPS. I don't even see the GPS sign in the notification. Some trouble with the consent when running as a service.